# Inconsistent div width after rotating device

Tags: css, iphone, wordpress, mobile-safari, fluid-layout

I have a fluid layout with page navigation on the bottom. I get my navigation to display correctly on all platforms I've been able to get my hands on, but there's an inconsistency in iOS' Safari.

Safari does not display the navigation correctly in portrait orientation, but **if I rotate it to landscape mode, and then to portrait again it's fine**.

The HTML for my navigation looks like this:

```
<nav id="nav-below">

    <div class="nav-previous">
        <a href="#" rel="prev">Previous link</a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-next">
        <a href="#" rel="next">Next link</a
    </div>                      

</nav>
```

The `nav` container should take up the full width of its parent and the two contained `div`s should take up 50% of `nav`. Here is my (simplified) CSS:

```
nav {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav-below {
    margin:2em 9% 0;
    padding:1em 0 0;
    border-top:4px double #e2f7ed;
}

.nav-previous {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This displays correctly in IE, Firefox, and Chrome, no matter the viewport size on the initial page load. But in the iPhone's Safari, the width of the `nav` container is less than half the width of its parent container until I've rotated my screen to landscape orientation and back. I've uploaded an image [here](http://tinypic.com/r/xnripx/8) to show you what it looks like.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and/or how to fix this? If it helps, [here](http://lucky-stars.ca/ptp/cheese-cookies) is a link to my site.

Comment: It happens in Chrome for iOS as well.

Comment: Have you tried removing your width:50% and just rely on floats? Maybe set the display to inline-block instead of block? It's really difficult to test this without a Fiddle or something :(

Comment: @Sophisticake Thanks, but since these are block level elements, removing the width would set these `div`s to 100% width by default, rendering the floats useless.

Comment: My gut tells me this isn't so much of a problem that can be easily explained with the code you've posted. If you can recreate the issue in a Fiddle, or provide a way to test the code so I can edit it on my iPhone, I don't see how anyone could figure it out. Let me know, I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `overflow: hidden;` fixes the issue. It was the only thing I could see that tends to cause layout problems, so I tried removing it. I needed this to make other things in the layout work, but I was able to work around it.

It's still very strange to me that the issue was not present after rotating the device and I'd be curious to hear if anyone knows why that is.